# sdkmanager --licenses не работает

Tags: android, android-sdk, react-native, webstorm, sdk

Запускаю проект. (npm start -> npm run android). Вылетает ошибка (после npm run android):

```
> Configure project :app
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in C:\Users\Igor\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in C:\Users\Igor\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Igor\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Please accept all necessary SDK licenses using SDK Manager: "$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses". Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Захожу в `C:\Users\Igor\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`
Ввожу в cmd `sdkmanager --licenses` вылазит просто список, всех команд sdkmanager, так же происходит если я ввожу команды например `sdkmanager --version` (--verbose вводил, без результата)

Comment: Я сейчас попробовал - список всех команд выводится только через `--help`.  Может быть у вас какая-то старая версия `sdkmanager`, которая не знает таких команд? Попробуйте обновить отсюда: https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads (под заголовком **Command line tools only**). И для верности зайдите всё-таки в `C:\Users\Igor\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\` и запустите команду оттуда - вдруг у вас в Path прописаны тулзы вовсе не из этого SDK.

Comment: @woesss Да, установка актуального sdkmanager помогла, спасибо большое! (Я убил свой сон и не к чему не пришел)